# How does Kubernetes GC detect disk usage?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes node with a small root disk and a large disk plumbed into /var/lib/docker

Kubernetes does GC on disk images when the used space reaches X%. Whats it looking at though? I can't find it in the docs.

Just to clarify, if you've got / with 20GB of space and /var/lib/docker with a second disk of 100GB, if K8S looks a / the % free is much less, potentially than /var/lib/docker, but / doesn't change much where as the mapped in drive, does.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration info for kubelet cleanup of unused images and containers is here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/

Default for X% in the question is 90%; default cleanup target is 80%.

Comment: Thanks Jonah, that bit I do know, clearly I wasn't clear enough. My question is, 90% and 80% of what? Because if it reads the / partition thats much less than whats actually available to docker if you map in an extra partition

Comment: It looks like k8s intends to check capacity and utilization on the actual file system on which images are stored. See: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/images/image_gc_manager.go#L41 and  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/apis/stats/v1alpha1/types.go#L75